# Standardizing Currencies in a Database: Converting Salaries to Dollars in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, database, jupyter-notebook

[Example of the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Vi5.png)

Within the image, I have the following database, comprising approximately 80,000 rows. It contains salary values in various currencies from all possible countries. How can I make the entire column have the same currency type, converting all values to dollars? I'm working on this database in Jupyter Notebook

I don't now how to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.